# Integrating font awesome script in a rails navigation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fonts, font-awesome

New to rails and like to integrate the following script "font awesome character" to left side of the words "edit profile" however tried a few ways and its appears below the nav and unable to link. the two pieces to integrate is the link:

<%= link_to "Edit Profile", edit_user_registration_path %>

```
<i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
```

How i integrate the two 
Thank you for any support

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a block to a link to add content to the anchor tag

[Documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-link_to)

```
<%= link_to(edit_user_registration_path) do %>
  <i class="fa fa-pencil" aria-hidden="true"></i>
  Edit Profile
<% end %>
```